# Controlling Brickstuff with Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

I don't have much experience with electronics (I'm ok with programming). I have some Brickstuff lights in a Lego set. The lights are powered by 3 AA batteries. The Brickstuff documentation says that I should not connect then directly to an Arduino, as the current exceeds the Arduino limit. I want to use an Arduino to power the lights and activate them with a button, but I want to use the same power supply to feed the Arduino and the lights.

Any suggestions about what components I should use, and how to connect them? Thanks.

Comment: You need a transistor.  Google, "using a transistor as a switch".

Answer (score 0):

Transistor is likely what you want for simplicity.

Be sure to add up all your amperage requirements and then add some extra when selecting a supply.  Having too little available will make your circuit misbehave while having a supply capable of giving you more doesn't hurt.

For voltage 3×1.5V = 4.5V if the batteries are in series.  Arduino runs on 5V (USB).  I suspect you'll probably be using a 5V supply.  Both circuits have a little margin, lights usually more so.